# Is there any order to the Lorule dungeons?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I just got to Lorule and have no idea where to go. Previous games had a kind of metroidvania type system where the item from one dungeon unlocked the next. Now that I can rent/buy most of the items, I'm not sure where to start. I made it into one dungeon, but it seemed like I needed some specific equipment to purges part the entrance and nothing I had aces to seemed to work. Is there any sort of order to the dungeons in this game?

Answer (score 6):

Except for the Desert Palace, you can do the Lorule dungeons in any order.

> You must complete the Thieves' Hideout before entering the Desert Palace, since Osfala rented the Sand Rod and cannot return it to Ravio until you save him.

Comment: I would do the Thieve's Hideout first, and then the Desert Palace for the Titan's Mitt, get the second Master Ore from Lorule's Sanctuary mini-dungeon, and then Water Palace for the Blue Wear that halves damage.

Comment: @WoF: Knowing what I know now, that sounds like a decent order for the dungeons. I might pop into the Dark Palace and Skull Woods for the other ores and get the gold sword before going back for the bosses

Comment: That sounds like something for Hero mode, in normal mode, the bosses are just too easy and deal next to no damage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you really need the Sand Rod and Titan’s Mitt to really go anywhere in the overworlds, I would hit:

1. Thieves Hideout
2. Desert Palace

After that I would tackle the rest in this order, reflecting the easiest to hardest boss fight:

3. Swamp Palace
4. Turtle Rock
5. Ice Ruins
6. Skull Woods
7. Dark Palace

Comment: Getting the super lantern before attempting the Dark Palace will make things a lot easier.

Answer (score -2):

There is no order, but, I would suggest swamp palace 1st so you can get the blue mail.